# PHP script for uploading multiple images to server

Tags: php, android, image-uploading

I have used the following code http://mayanklangalia.blogspot.co.ke/2014/04/how-to-upload-multiple-images-on-php.html in my application and it is working fine on the android studio side, i am however stranded on how to write the php script to upload these multiple selected images to the server. I already know how to write the script for uploading a single image using this code

```
     <?php
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {



 $image = $_POST['image'];
 require_once('DB_Connect.php');







 $sql ="SELECT id FROM images ORDER BY id ASC";
 $now = DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', microtime(true));
 $id = $now->format('ymdhisu');
  $path = "Upload/$id.jpeg";
 $actualpath = "http://myurl/$path";
 $sql = "INSERT INTO volleyupload (photo) VALUES ('$actualpath')";




   if( file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($image))!=false){
    echo "Successfully Uploaded";
    exit;
}  
    } else {
echo "Error";
   }
    ?>
```

but i am not sure how to go about writing the script for multiple images.

Comment: i would recommend looking at what is being sent to the php by doing this.
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);

this will allow you to see all post data, then you can see if you have an array of images in $_POST['image']

Answer (score 0):

An example script for multiple image upload up to 100KB, if the upload file size exceeds 100KB, then program won't allow user to upload the image.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$j = 0; //Variable for indexing uploaded image 

$target_path = "uploads/"; //Declaring Path for uploaded images
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++) { //loop to get individual element from the array

    $validextensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png"); //Extensions which are allowed
    $ext = explode('.', basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$i])); //explode file name from dot(.) 
    $file_extension = end($ext); //store extensions in the variable

    $target_path = $target_path.md5(uniqid()).
    ".".$ext[count($ext) - 1]; //set the target path with a new name of image
    $j = $j + 1; //increment the number of uploaded images according to the files in array       

    if (($_FILES["file"]["size"][$i] < 100000) //Approx. 100kb files can be uploaded.
        && in_array($file_extension, $validextensions)) {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path)) { //if file moved to uploads folder
            echo $j.
            ').<span id="noerror">Image uploaded successfully!.</span><br/><br/>';
        } else { //if file was not moved.
            echo $j.
            ').<span id="error">please try again!.</span><br/><br/>';
        }
    } else { //if file size and file type was incorrect.
        echo $j.
        ').<span id="error">***Invalid file Size or Type***</span><br/><br/>';
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Why does this work? What was the OP doing wrong? This will solve their problem for now, but will not help them in the future or help future viewers.

Comment: Llias i have tried your code above with slightly few modifications, now it sends me a response of picture uploaded successfully yet the picture does not appear on my server. What could i be doing wrong?

Comment: Llias i have tried your code above with slightly few modifications, now it sends me a response of picture uploaded successfully yet the picture does not appear on my server. What could i be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following script and it worked in regards to the question i posted above.

```
      <?php

      require_once('DB_Connect.php');


      $name = $_POST["name"];
      $image = $_POST["IMAGE"];
      $decodedImage = base64_decode("$image");


      $actualpath = "http://aerialssnip/public_html/$path";
      $sql = "INSERT INTO volleyupload (photo) VALUES ('$actualpath')";

      file_put_contents($path,$decodeImage);



    ?>
```